# Grep Recursively for files in specific group of sub folders

Tags: linux, grep

I've done a search through both Google and StackOverflow, but haven't seemed to be able to find an answer to this question. It might be because I'm searching the wrong terms, but hopefully someone can help!

I have the following file structure similar to this:

```
/logs/ServiceA/Prod/2017/10/01/11/logFileForHour
/logs/ServiceA/Prod/2017/10/01/12/logFileForHour
/logs/ServiceA/Prod/2017/10/01/13/logFileForHour
/logs/ServiceB/SubService1/Prod/2017/10/01/12/logFileForHour
/logs/ServiceC/SubService1/Prod/Mirror/2017/10/01/12/logFileForHour
/logs/ServiceC/SubService1/Beta/2017/10/01/12/logFileForHour
```

Each hour's folder contains the aggregate of the logs from all hosts running that service. Those hourly folders are aggregated into daily folders, which are aggregated into monthly folders and so on. Then the logs are aggregated by Stage (Prod/Demo/Dev) and then further by Service/SubService.

I need a way to grep for a common identifier across all PROD services, and sub services and would like to try and do this with a single grep if at all possible. I know the hour that the request was placed in.

Ideally I'd be able to use a filepath of: `/logs/*/Prod/*/2017/10/01/12/*` if I wanted all prod logs from all services and sub services during the 12:00 hour of October 10th, 2017, but this only works if there is a single folder where each asterisk is, when in reality that could be 1 or more folders for the first asterisk and 0 or more folders for the second asterisk.

Any help you all could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
find logs -type d -name Prod | xargs grep -r SEARCHSTRING
```

but beware I couldn't test it...

EDIT after clarification:

```
find logs -type f -path '*/Prod/*' -a -path '*/2017/10/01/12/*'
```

which is, find all files descendants of a path that matches `Prod` and matches the date/hour path you are looking for (add grep)

Comment: Thanks GUDO for the initial edit. I've updated my question to better reflect exactly what I'm trying to do. I know for certain what hour the request I'm looking for occurred, so I'd rather not grep through logs that dont correspond to that hour.

Comment: Sure, I only thought you were looking to solve the multiple directories to be matched first; see update answer, find -path looks like what you need.

Comment: Thanks GUDO, that did exactly what I needed.